# Performance hit when drawing on canvas using GPU

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gpu, html5-canvas

Using Chrome 12 my game is drawing smoothly. But Chrome 14, which appears to use the GPU for drawing, has an enormous negative impact on the performance of my game.

I made a jsFiddle to see when exactly it happens and this simple code is already running into problems: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/48/.

- On Chrome 12, the FPS is 62, which is even more than my screen frequency.
- On Chrome 14, the FPS is ~25.

25 FPS is quite acceptable, but in my game I'm drawing even more and it is running down to ~8 FPS there, which definitely is *not* acceptable. I've never had any performance problems but the GPU update for canvas is a bottleneck for me.

- Why is some simple drawing on canvas so much slower using the GPU?
- Can I disable Chrome from using the GPU through JavaScript? (Or is there another solution for this?)

---

**Edit:** Filed a bug at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=89540

Comment: Getting 60fps in 3 different versions of chrome (the webkitRequestAnimationFrame limit)  :)

Comment: @cwolves: Might it be my GPU which is not improving anything? (I'm using a laptop, which I once read do not have so good GPUs or something.)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/50/ <-- using a timer, getting ~200fps in chrome 12 & 2 versions of chrome 14 (new macbook pro).  Yes, it's theoretically possible that your GPU is slowing things down for this example because of the CPU-->GPU-->CPU round trip actually being more expensive than the rendering in this example (it's a very simple example).  I'd be curious what you get for some of the examples on https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/, which are much more complicated

Comment: @cwolves: Thanks, but same thing there. Around 70 FPS for Chrome 12, still 25 for Chrome 14.

Comment: @cwolves: three.js is also jerkier on Chrome 14 for me. 16 FPS on Chrome 12 for `canvas_particles_sprites.html` and only 8 on Chrome 14.

Comment: You have a really crappy GPU?  :)  Either that or Chrome's GPU code isn't that optimized yet.  Have you tried FF4 vs FF5 (same thing -- FF5 has GPU acceleration)

Comment: @cwolves: I only have Firefox 6 on which I too get 62 FPS. So perhaps it's actually not my GPU, I'm not sure.

Comment: The simple explanation is probably that Chrome 14 just sucks at talking to _your_ GPU.  That doesn't mean that will always be the case, and in general GPU rendering is ___far___ superior to CPU rendering.  What exact version of Chrome 14 are you using?  I'm running 14.0.823 (canary) && 14.0.803 (dev)

Comment: @cwolves: I'm using Chrome 14.0.817.0 (build 91952) which I recently downloaded from the nightly builds page. And it says my GPU is `Mobile Intel(R) 965 Express Chipset Family`. Might it be a good idea to perhaps file a bug using this data?

Comment: FYI, I just ran into the ___exact___ same issue when I forced GPU acceleration on and ran one of my canvas pages, so it's not just you.

Comment: Btw, you should use requestAnimationFrame. It would probably make you get a better fps.

Comment: @xavierm02: I'm doing that already in fact (`webkitRequestAnimationFrame`).

Comment: Right my bad >_< I just saw the setInterval and thought it was the thing doing the animation... But instead of using the one just for webkit, you could use that : http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: @xavierm02: Thanks, in fact I'm using that snippet in my real game already. It doesn't do much in terms of permorfance though, because it simply puts `webkitRequestAnimationFrame` into `requestAnimFrame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed Chromium `14.0.831.0 build 93677` (as opposed to `14.0.917.0 build 91952`) and things were fine again. It's now just *under* 60 FPS instead of ~62, but oh well...

I guess the main point is that things come and go too fast with nightly builds. My game is running fine again (and since today the latest nightly build uses the new WebSocket protocol which is a great as well).

I hope I'm not getting too fired up of this as it might just slow down next week again, but I'll see.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting 60fps in Chrome 14 just fine.

I can almost guarantee this is due to hardware acceleration being on by default in Chrome 14 and not in 12. Specifically the waiting for vertical sync, which didn't happen before.

In Chrome 14 and beyond GPU accel (of Canvas) is no longer a flag you can turn on and off - it is a default. Sorry.

You can however still disable GPU Vsync in Chrome 14 if you go to `chrome://flags/`. This will almost certainly give you more frames.

However it is not something you can make your users do.

Comment: I'm not that much into the world of GPU - is hardware acceleration a negative thing?

Comment: No, typically its a positive thing. Having vertical Sync will pin it to a much slower speed though, so if you want to compare past benchmarks to current ones, you're going to have to take that off.

Comment: Vertical sync means that it will clamp the frame rate to the screen's refresh rate, which is usually 60Hz.

Comment: @kcbanner: In that case, shouldn't I still get ~60 FPS? I don't see how that can cause the FPS to drop to 25.

Comment: It gets a little complicated, but here is a very good explanation of why its not as simple as "cap at 60FPS" and more like "slow things down across the board": http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=928593

Comment: The gist of it is: "Essentially this means that with double-buffered VSync, the framerate can only be equal to a discrete set of values equal to Refresh / N where N is some positive integer. That means if you're talking about 60Hz refresh rate, the only framerates you can get are 60, 30, 20, 15, 12, 10, etc etc. You can see the big gap between 60 and 30 there. Any framerate between 60 and 30 your video card would normally put out would get dropped to 30."

Comment: @Simon Sarris: Thanks for your explanation. It turned out to be something different, not sure what but upgrading to the latest nightly build resolved the issue.